# While page refresh in angular2.0 the page shows an error unexpected token <

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam getting error when reload the page when i use angular 2.0 . Because it is taking a wrong path to fetch the files like css and javascript file actually css in root folder but it is taken as wrong as index.html/styles.css please observe my sample code and error below

**System.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
 System.config({
// DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
transpiler: 'ts',
typescriptOptions: {
  tsconfig: true
},
meta: {
  'typescript': {
    "exports": "ts"
  }
},
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
  'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
  'typescript':                'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js',

},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.ts',
    defaultExtension: 'ts'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
 });})(this);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<title>Angular Tour of Heroes</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

```
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Below error as i got in console in the web browser

> GET ~URL /angular2/index.html/styles.css
>    GET ~URL /angular2/index.html/systemjs.config.js 
>    GET ~URL /angular2/index.html/systemjs.config.js
>
> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)

Comment: how are serving these files? are you sure your server is serving the files correctly? It is a common problem to serve index.html instead of js files in single page apps. :)

Comment: what web server you using for this?